# I get "ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE" on my website when i'm using proxy

Tags: nginx, bind, ubuntu-14.04, proxypass

I have a dedicated server with:

- Ubuntu 14.04.3
- BIND 9.9.5-3ubuntu0.5-Ubuntu (Extended Support Version)
- Nginx version 1.9.6 On Port 81
- PHP 5.5.30 (cli) with Zend OPcache v7.0.6-dev
- MySQL 5.5.45
- UFW enabled
- My Website: Drupal 7

Everything works.
But every time I'm connected to psiphon3 proxy (Anti filter), I get "ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE" on chrome browser:

```
No data received

ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

Unable to load the webpage because the server sent no data.
```

**Note:** Other websites like drupal.org respond.

I have checked Syslog, Nginx and Bind logs, but nothing helped me.

Maybe this is because of DNS configuration (Bind) Or Nginx, I don't know what the problem is in my server configurations. If more details of any service configuration is needed I can provide.

I need the website to respond when people are using proxy.